# jenkins setup plugins installation failed

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup jenkins on ec2 instance,
but when I was installing default plugins on homepage,
it failed over and over again without any prompts.
Thank you
[image]
I had tried to reboot my instance and setup a new instance, but not worked.

Comment: 2.204.1 is very old. You should use latest LTS (which needs Java 11). But your problem is likely you must set a proxy, which should appear in an earlier prompt, and egress also must be set in the instance too.

Comment: thanks for that, I guess the version is too old.

Comment: The real problem / cause will be the proxy/egress. You should be able to verify that by looking in the system logs. The fact that it's old is ancillary; not point in setting up an obsolete instance.

Comment: I didn't notice that at all, either I didn't see any proxy setting before that. However, it's workable to install plugins in manage plugin section. Thank you of all.